# getting formula about finding height of a vertical line in different positions in coordinate system.

Tags: analytic-geometry

[image]
I want to find height of a vertical line in different positions. I need a formula for calculating. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$H=mx+\frac{1}{2}h$$
where m is the slope of the line.

Comment: Thank you very much,

Comment: @noachloster you’re welcome!